# Verify the formula: $\int_1^4 g(\sqrt{x}) dx = 2 \int_1^2 xg(x) dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

How should I go about proving the following:

> > $$\int_1^4 g(\sqrt{x}) dx = 2 \int_1^2 xg(x) dx$$

Comment: Let $\sqrt{x}=t$,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$\int_1^4g(\sqrt{x})dx$$
$$x=u^2$$
$$dx=2udu$$
$$\int_1^4g(\sqrt{x})dx=\int_1^22g(\sqrt{u^2})udu=2\int_1^2ug(u)du=2\int_1^2xg(x)dx$$

Comment: Aww thanks man! I am so close. Watch somebody downvote this now.

Comment: Hah now if somebody downvoted you after reading the previous comments, the system should report that as abuse

Comment: @HarryAlli That's what I thought I should do but I don't understand how it turns from $\int_1^4$ to $\int_1^2$

Comment: @JohnDoe look more deeply into *u-substitution*

Comment: @JohnDoe you have to change the bounds with a u substitution.  I suggest you search definite integrals under u-substitution